# What is the best way to share UML/ER diagrams on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it possible to share the [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)/[ER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Overview) diagrams the same way we use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to share SQL code?

Do we have such online services?

I know about the inline rule, but with such services I want to prepare an environment in which it is easy to illistrate an answer! And from this point of view, an image is not enough.

Comment: An image won't suffice? What else do you have in mind? Keep in mind that even for a fiddle we require that you inline the code/content and only link to a fiddle in addition to that.

Comment: Also, sqlfiddle jsfiddle and other fiddles **should not** be used as main way of showing your code here. They are external services that can delete content whenever they want, rendering your posts unusable. Always post all relevant parts of your code directly into your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it: http://yuml.me .

And this is the sample: [image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to export your ER diagram to an image and simply use the image-upload feature. Is there something preventing you from doing that? Ideally you're only posting a section of your ER diagram also.

SQLFiddle should only be used as a demonstration of your code working (or failing to work). I would also argue that your main post should *also* contain the code in question.